# How to loop back to beginning

Tags: python, loops

How would i fix this:

```
print 'Adventure Game'

choice_1 = raw_input('You are travelling down a long road, there is a fork in the route, one side goes to a jungle, and the other leads to a hill biome, which side do you choose?            J for Jungle, H for Hill ')

if choice_1 == 'J':
    print 'Jungle?, very well then' 

elif choice_1 == 'H':
    print 'Hill, good decision'

if choice_1 == 'J':
    choice_2 = raw_input('In the jungle, a king cobra appears behind you, as you look forward, an ape leaps from a tree onto the ground. Do you take your chances with the venomous king cobra, or the enormous ape? C for cobra, A for ape ')

while choice_2 != 'A':
    print 'Sorry, you were bit by the cobra and died'
    print 'Please try again'

if choice_2 == 'A':
    break

elif choice_2 == 'A':
    print 'You were almost mauled by the ape, luckily, it fleed the scene after loosing sight of you'
```

i want it to restart if the user chooses c for choice_2, and so that it starts from the beginning every single time that this happens

Comment: You should try wrapping your code in a function, and then call the function again once the user in the game dies.

Comment: You want to try and avoid a lot of `if, elif` statements because it will take you a very long time to code. Use classes for your players and enemies. You can use functions as locations and a main `while True` loop for your main game

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using functions for each location, that way you can call the same function multiple times or inside other functions.

For example:

```
def road():
    choice = ''
    while choice not in ['j','h']:
        choice = raw_input('You are travelling down a long road, there is a fork in the route, one side goes to a jungle, and the other leads to a hill biome, which side do you choose?            J for Jungle, H for Hill ').lower()
    if choice == 'j':
        jungle()
    elif choice == 'h':
        hill()

def jungle():
    choice = ''
    while choice not in ['c','a']:
        choice = raw_input('In the jungle, a king cobra appears behind you, as you look forward, an ape leaps from a tree onto the ground. Do you take your chances with the venomous king cobra, or the enormous ape? C for cobra, A for ape ').lower()

    if choice == 'c':
        print 'Sorry, you were bit by the cobra and died'
        print 'Please try again'
        return
    elif choice == 'a':
        print 'You were almost mauled by the ape, luckily, it fleed the scene after loosing sight of you'
        next_func_here()

while True:
    print 'Adventure Game Starts Here!'
    road()
    print 'restarting...'
```

This way you can keep adding functions quickly and easily, and is also easier to debug.
The `while` loop means that if `road()` exits, it loops back to the beginning and restarts `road()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print 'Adventure Game'
choice_1 = raw_input('You are travelling down a long road, there is a fork in the route, one side goes to a jungle, and the other leads to a hill biome, which side do you choose?            J for Jungle, H for Hill ')
if choice_c == 'J':
    while True:
        choice_2 = raw_input('In the jungle, a king cobra appears behind you, as you look forward, an ape leaps from a tree onto the ground. Do you take your chances with the venomous king cobra, or the enormous ape? C for cobra, A for ape ')
        if choice_2 != 'A':
            print 'Sorry, you were bit by the cobra and died'
            print 'Please try again'
        elif choice_2 == 'A':
            print 'You were almost mauled by the ape, luckily, it fleed the scene after loosing sight of you'
            break
elif choice_1 == 'H':
    print 'Hill, good decision'
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do an input at the bottom that says "would you like to continue?" and set it to a variable. Then wrap your entire game in a while loop.

```
cont = True
while continue == True:
    #put all your code here
    cont = input("Would you like to continue? (T/F)")
```

Comment: don't use reserved keyword as key variable